# I am trying to position an info box over an image but still have both stay inside the container

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have tried things like using position absolute on one and position relative on the other but it always messes up one so that it overflows even though i have set overflow to hidden. This is my code so far.(ignore the fact that it says className and not class)

```
<div className="card">
      <div className="img">
        <img src={props.image} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className="infoContainer">
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        <h3>{props.description}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

that is the jsx

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.infoContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.img {
}
```

anyone have any ideas? Any help is much appreciated.
This is the output of what i have so far im not sure what to do. Im trying to get the image to be where the dark blue is.
[image: The dark blue is where im trying to get the image to show up]

Comment: It isn't clear what "over" means in this context, but I think you're trying to implement functionality that already exists by setting "background-image" through CSS

Comment: [`figure` and  `figcaption`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) might be more suited to your needs here

Comment: @Jon P yes i may just do that.

Comment: @LucasLaValva I want a card that contains an image at the top with an info box below like this: https://speckyboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/css-content-cards-05.jpg

Comment: Given that info, figure and figcaption is not what you want.

Comment: I would use background-image but I am using react and am passing in image urls as props to this card component and im not sure that is possible without 3rd party extensions

Comment: Is there any overlap between image and info? Hence the info box being "over" the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position:relative` on the `card`. That way any contained elements with `postion:absolute` will be positioned relative to the card element

```css
.card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*By settign this to relative, absolutely positioned
   descendant elements will be positioned relative to this
  */
  position: relative;
}

.infoContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  /*Position the infoContainer*/
  position: absolute;
  /*Set it to the bottom*/
  bottom: 0;
  /*Bring it to the front*/
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.img {}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="img">
    <img src=https://www.fillmurray.com/400/500 alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="infoContainer">
    <h2>Bill Murray</h2>
    <h3>Star of the classic film Garfield</h3>
    <!--<h2>{props.title}</h2>
    <h3>{props.description}</h3>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
position:relative;
```

for card. Then set .img (try using .img img{} if not working) properties to

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0vh;
width: 100%;
```

I hope it can be undersood :-)